# How to define a query parameter with name but no value?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm creating Swagger documentation for an URL that looks like this:

```
mysite.local.com/mylink?callback&service=someservicename&currency=USD
```

As you can see, the `callback` parameter in the query string has a name but no value. How do I describe this parameter in Swagger?

Here's the YAML code I'm using:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
 title: My API
 description: Documentation of webservices Used
 version: 1.0.0

host: mysite.local.com
basePath: /
schemes:
 - https

paths:
 /mylink:
   get:
     summary: sometext
     description: Optional extended description in Markdown.
     produces:
       - application/json
     responses:
       200:
        description: OK
     parameters:
      callback:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the [doc](https://swagger.io/specification/#fixed-fields-51) that you can specify a parameter that is in the "query", but i'm pretty sure you'll have to give it a value (ie : ?callback=true)

Example :

```
paths:
 /mylink:
   get:
     summary: sometext
     description: Optional extended description in Markdown.
     produces:
       - application/json
     responses:
       200:
        description: OK
     parameters:
      - name: callback
        in: query
        type: boolean
```

Comment: how do I add service and currency parameters?

Comment: Same way :

     parameters:
      - name: callback
        in: query
        type: boolean
      - name: service
        in: query
        type: string
      - name: currency
        in: query
        type: string

Comment: can I somehow do it with `?callback` instead of `?callback=true`?

Comment: you can do it with "/callback?service=someservicename&currency=USD". I'm not sure that you can do it the way you want

Comment: To use `?callback` without a value, add `allowEmptyValue: true` to the parameter definition.

Comment: @Helen : according to this topic (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1396) i'm not sure that it is possible to have only "?callback" (ie : get "?callback=")